# How to change a font and color of a letter in math mode in all document?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, color, letters

I try to change the font and color of x,y and z in math mode

`\setmathfont[range={"78,"79,"7A},Color=red]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`

but it doesn't work!

for example if I try

`\setmathfont[range={"7B},Color=red]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`

it works and changes the color of `{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `unicode-math` the upright and italic math alphabets have different Unicode codepoints, and also different macro names.  By default, `$x$` gives you  (U+1D465), which is `\mitx`, and likewise for `\mity` and `\mitz`, [as you can look up here.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)

You can use the commands `\mitx`, `\symit{x}` or `\mathnormal{x}` within the body of the document.  If you want `\mathit` to also work, you will have to pass `unicode-math` the option `[mathit=sym]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[
  range={\mitx,\mity,\mitz},
  Color=red]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ \mitx^2 + \symit{y}^2 = \mathnormal{z}^2 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Pagella font sample]

You can use any of the following formats within the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`:

```
range={` ,"1D466,\mitz}
```